# Laravel Eloquent - Get results from parents that has only one child

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, parent-child

I'm trying to get all results that match a certain child id, and that the parent has only on child. My initial idea its to do it by hand with nested foreachs, but is there any method that does this in a simpler way?

My parent is called `Proyectos` and then I have a pivot table called `PaisBeneficiarioProyecto`, and the other parent is `PaisBeneficiario`. It's a `many-to-many` relation.

```
$monto_pais = Proyecto::all()->where('pais_beneficiarios', $id)->sum('monto_aprobado');
```

The code explained above does what you expect, but it's not the result that I need.
Here are my models:

`Proyectos`:

```
public function pais_beneficiarios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\PaisBeneficiario::class, 'pais_beneficiario_proyecto', 'id_proyecto', 'id_pais_beneficiario')
                    ->withPivot('monto_beneficio');
    }
```

`PaisBeneficiario`:

```
public function pais_beneficiario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\PaisBeneficiario::class, 'id_pais_beneficiario');
    }

    public function proyecto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Proyecto::class, 'id_proyecto');
    }
```

`PaisBeneficiarioProyectos`:

```
public function proyectos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Proyecto::class, 'pais_beneficiario_proyecto', 'id_pais_beneficiario', 'id_proyecto')
                    ->withPivot('monto_beneficio');
    }
```

The value that I'm trying to sum is called `monto_aprobado` which is on `Proyectos`

Comment: I edited the question with the info requested :)

Comment: It's not clear what you want, please describe the problem and what you expect clearly.

Comment: I want the query to return only the "Proyectos" that have only one "PaisBeneficiarioProyecto" child and that "PaisBeneficiario", has the id that im looking for. Its like the query that i posted on the question but, adding the condition that "Proyectos" has to have only one child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query gives you the sum of `monto_aprobado` field of `Proyecto` models that jus have one `pais_beneficiarios_count`.

```
Proyecto::withCount('pais_beneficiarios')
    ->having('pais_beneficiarios_count', 1)
    ->sum('monto_aprobado');
```

Comment: Hi, it gives me this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pais_beneficiarios_count' in 'having clause' (SQL: select sum(`monto_aprobado`) as aggregate from `proyecto` having `pais_beneficiarios_count` = 1). The query is very close, but idk why i can't find that column, because i tested withcount and then get(), and the column is on every result that it gives back.

Comment: Nevermind, i added a ->get() after ->having() and it worked wonderfully, thank you :))))